# svjour3 10pt problem

Tags: fontsize

I am using svjour3 and font size in article is too small. I want 10pt but end up with 9pt.

```
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
    \documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
    \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \algsetup{linenosize=\scriptsize} 
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
    \begin{document}
```

Comment: I am using pdflatex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Where do you see that a fontsize of 9pt is used?

Answer (score 1):

If you make your document terminate and show the fonts used:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\algsetup{linenosize=\scriptsize} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
\begin{document}

\showoutput
a

\end{document}
```

Then you see in the log

```
.......\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 a
```

Confirming the main document font is 10pt Times Roman (Assuming the default fd files).